# Differences of proportions over time with dependent choices?

Tags: bayesian, proportion, independence, mlogit

I'll try to summarise my problem:

I have a memory study where people (after some experimental procedures) have to make a choice regarding 100 different photos. The choices in each photo are always the same (say A,B,C), and every participant perform 100 choices (100 photos). This process is repeated 1 day later and 2 days later. (300 choices in total)

This was not a target analysis in my paper but it gives some interesting information so I calculated the percentage of (A,B,C) choices x participant in each time (1,2,3) and performed a Two way ANOVA with percentages. I am aware that it is not the best option (1) because actually I've count data (2) because I am bot controlling for ID and (3) and the most important - A,B,C are dependent categories (if A choices = 80% B + C choices can only sum 20%). I am having a hard time trying to find a solution. My best option now is a mixed multinomial logit model, including (1) every single choice (100 x 3Times x participant) (2) choice options of every photo (a repeated string of A,B,C) (3) Time (4) |ID. I am not sure if this kind of modelling will answer my question. That in fact which is the most prevalent answer (A,B,C) depending on Time (1,2,3). Someone told me "you have to use bayesian statistics" ... of course it would be nice but I only know the very basics of B.S. and it has been impossible for me to find HOW to do it.

Please, tell me whatever you think about that!

Comment: A multinomial logistic regression with repeated measures is probably the best option, indeed. What makes you think it won't answer your research question? The thing is that it depends on the software you use. Bayesian computation is involved in, e.g., [MCMCglmm](https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/multinomial-random-effects-models-in-r/) in R, while [multilevel approaches](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/semexample41g.pdf) like generalized structural equation modeling are used in Stata (and probably [gllamm](http://www.gllamm.org/)).

Comment: What do you mean by *bot controlling*?

Comment: not controlling** sorry